# Django Unit Test Assert Database Transaction is Active

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unit-testing, transactions

We are writing some unit tests to assert that at certain points inside functions there is a database transaction active. However, we are struggling how to exactly assert this, does anyone know how we can do this? Browsing the [Django Transaction Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/) and the [Source Code for django.db.transaction](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/db/transaction.py) did not turn up anything useful.

Here is some code to illustrate what we are trying to achieve, using [Assertion Injection](http://redsymbol.net/articles/assertion-injection/):

```
def function_under_test():
    ... some stuff ....
    function_we_will_patch_to_assert_transaction_is_open()
    ... some more stuff ...

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def assert_transaction_is_active(self):
        self.assertTrue(...what goes in here to assert this?...)

    @patch('function_we_will_patch_to_assert_transaction_is_open'):
    def test_function_under_test__transaction_is_active(self, patched_fn):
        patched_fn.side_effect = self.assert_transaction_is_active

        function_under_test()
```

One note: We are really keen to do this in a database agnostic way (we use sqlite in dev and postgresql elsewhere), however if there are solutions that only work for postgresql then that would be workable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We managed to achieve this by adding the following function to the test class.

```
def assert_inside_atomic_block(self, using=None):
    """
    Returns a function that will assert we are inside an atomic transaction block. The purpose of this is to allow
    us to inject this assertion inside methods where we want to verify that a transaction is active.

    Does not work with django.db.TransactionTestCase because it automatically wraps each test in a transaction.
    """

    if issubclass(self.__class__, TransactionTestCase):
        raise AssertionError('Cannot determine if code is run inside a transaction with a TransactionTestCase')

    def _assert_inside_atomic_block(*args, **kwargs):
        if not get_connection(using=using).in_atomic_block:
            raise AssertionError('Not inside an atomic transaction block')

    return _assert_inside_atomic_block
```

Which can then be used in a test as follows:

```
@patch('function_we_will_patch_to_assert_transaction_is_open'):
def test_function_under_test__transaction_is_active(self, patched_fn):
    patched_fn.side_effect = self.assert_inside_atomic_block()

    function_under_test()
```

One important point to note: This technique does not work with test classes based on `django.test.TransactionTestCase` - because this wraps every test in a transaction the assertion will never fail.